# How do I query using Mongoose, but then take that document to do other things?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, doc){
   //do stuff with "doc" here.
});
```

That's the way I currently do it. But what if I want to take "doc", and just do stuff.

```
User.findOne({}, function(err, doc){
   //do stuff with "doc" here.
});
runAnotherFunction(doc.name)
doc...
```

How do I take "doc" out of the "function" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node is event driven, it's not procedural code like you're probably used to. Before mongoose can finish retrieving a record execution can already be well passed the call the findOne. Anything that needs to be done with the doc should happen in the callback (The "function" part).

Comment: So, I can't take the contents of "doc" out of the callback part?  What if I need to grab the person's gender, and use it outside of the callback....

Comment: @TIMEX Take a look at [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step), this forces serialized execution possible in Node.

Comment: John, is there tutorial that gets me thinking the node.js way? I'm thinking procedural right now and I have no idea how to write non-procedural.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "step" , 
https://github.com/creationix/step

This makes it easier to control logic flow.

See this for example :

[async nodejs querying and processing results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807838/mongodb-and-nodejs)

Comment: Step is good for when you need controlled flow, but keep in mind if you're using it excessively what's the point of using an event driven language.

Comment: @JohnD  I agree, I am not much aware of NodeJS